# Can I flight check-in on someone’s else behalf?

Tags: contract-law, internet, software, international

I am not sure if this is the right place to post this and if not please guide me to correct forum.

I am building a software that’ll help travellers with their flights. It’ll auto check-in to the flights for them.
My question is, is it legally allowed or possible to do that? If you remember they have this terms and conditions screen before that you need to agree before you proceed for check-in. I’ll also add all those terms and conditions and ask user to agree on it before using my software and take a consent from them my software will do a check-in on their behalf. But is allowed even?
Also, just for reference, there’s a website passnfly.com that does a similar stuff and I don’t know if they have permission for it or what.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It probably varies from one country to another and from one airline to another.  You might be able to do this for Lufthansa flights originating in Canada but not for Lufthansa flights from the US or for Air France flights from Canada.  I suspect that in most cases the answer is *no,* but in general this question is rather too broad.  If I were you I would start by looking for airlines that expose a public API for their check-in systems.  I suspect you won't find many.

Comment: Thanks for a prompt reply. There are actually no airlines that expose such APIs. But then there’s this passnfly.com that does for most of them and I am not sure how did they figure out permission thing. You know any resource that I can read that can help me with it?

Comment: I can only offer that Delta and Hawaiian have allowed me to check in my spouse and visa versa when the tickets were purchased together. Not a legal answer, but a practical demonstration that it is allowed under some cirucmstances by some airlines.